# UdpClient stops sending messages after second client joins

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-standard, udpclient

I have some code for a server and client, with the server potentially having multiple clients. When it is one client and one server, I am sending and receiving messages perfectly. However, when a second user joins, the clients no longer receive the messages.

Here's how I'm sending the messages serverside:

```cs
if (Clients.Count == 0)
    return;
foreach (ConnectedClient client in Clients)
{
    BinaryFormatter messageFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    try
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
                messageFormatter.Serialize(ms, new Message() { Content = new GameData(Clients), MessageType = EServerCommand.GameUpdate, origin = (IPEndPoint)Client.Client.LocalEndPoint });
                Client.Send(ms.ToArray(), ms.ToArray().Length, new IPEndPoint(client.ConnectionPlayer.ClientIP, 42070));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         return;
    }
}
```

Clientside, I am receiving the messages like so:

```cs
public async void HandleServerMessages()
{
    while(true)
    {
        var message = await Receive();
        if (message.MessageType == EServerCommand.GameUpdate)
        {
            GameUpdateEvent((GameData)message.Content);
        }
    }
}

public override async Task<Message> Receive()
{
    var result = await Client.ReceiveAsync();
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        memStream.Write(result.Buffer, 0, result.Buffer.Length);
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var message = formatter.Deserialize(memStream);
        return (Message)message;
    }
}
```

Like I mentioned earlier, a single client and server works as expected, the problems only arise when a second client connects.

EDIT: I have since tried using wireshark, it seems the client computer is receiving the packets, but the client code is not registering this as a "receive". Here's what wireshark is showing (10.0.0.157 is the computer, 10.0.0.170 is the server.

[image]

Comment: Do you start two clients on the same machine?

Comment: @Tarik One on the local machine, one on another on the same network. If the client on the different computer joins first it receives the messages until I join, and vice versa.

Comment: Then the problem is with the server code that cannot handle two concurrent clients.

Comment: @Tarik I'm using the standard UdpClient in the C# library, does that not support concurrent clients?

Comment: No, the problem is server side, probably ignoring one of the clients. How do you know the only one client works?

Comment: I have breakpoints set and `await Client.ReceiveAsync()` runs when it's one client, but stops when the second joins. I have since tried using WireShark and see that the computer is receiving the data, but the code isn't saying it's being received after the second client joins.

Comment: What you are saying confirms that the problem is with the server. I wanted to ask you to use Wireshark, but you did :-)

Comment: If the client computer is getting the message but the code isn't finding it, would that indicate a client issue?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. You mean that the client PC is receiving the udp packet. Well, Wireshark will see all the packets. Probably different IP or port. Make sure it is the exact same.

Comment: I still think it is a server problem though.

Comment: I think you are getting into the exception handler and not processing the message.  You cannot deserialize a message until the entire message is received.  The message may not come in one chunk.  So with binary data you have to proceed the message with a byte count and the wait until the entire serialized message is received before deserialize.